# livepatchd Cannot get current kernel version fork/exec /uname no such file or directory

Tags: canonical-livepatch

While debugging a separate issue I found a lot of lines like this in /var/log/syslog:

> canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd[1157]: Cannot get current kernel version: fork/exec /uname: no such file or directory.

Been googling for a while but havent found anything useful.

```
$ whereis uname
uname: /usr/bin/uname /usr/share/man/man1/uname.1.gz /usr/share/man/man2/uname.2.gz
```

I dont think it has any practical effect other than livepatch maybe not working though it seems fine from the ui:
[image: screenshot showing a healthy livepatch ui]

Running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

`uname -a` shows:

> Linux bruce 5.17.15-051715-generic #202206141358 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jun 14 18:53:59 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Any idea on how to troubleshoot/fix this?

Comment: Maybe you could start by explicitly stating which kernel you're running? Please include the output of `uname -a` in your question.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Thanks for the tip, I edited the question with the output from uname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're running a non-standard kernel.

Livepatch supports a limited number of standard kernels, as [indicated here](https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch/docs/kernels).

You should install the latest official kernel for Ubuntu 22.04 (which is kernel line 5.15) to take advantage of the Livepatch service.

Comment: Aghhh I missed that... going back to 5.15.57 to test, that might actually solve the other problem Im having with my nvidia drivers... will post back in a bit. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: No, don't install mainline kernels. Install [this package with Ubuntu Kernel version 5.15.0-43](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/linux-image-generic). Mainline kernels will not work with livepatch either. You really have to decide if you want custom kernels or livepatch. Right now it seems maybe you're better off with custom kernels and no livepatch. Also, IMO livepatch isn't really that critical, if you install custom kernels anyway.

Comment: Also, please upvote in any case if my answer is helpful. 

Comment: well I ran 5.15.57 for a while and the nvidia problems got much better, about 1hr ago I switched to 5.15.0-43 as per your suggestion and so far I havent seen any flickering or any problem at all so I think you just solved my 2 issues. If any of them comes back I know for sure its a mismatch between kernel and nvidia driver versions :) Much obliged!